# Android list view inside tab focus issue

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I have a TabHost with a ListView inside a tab. When the activity starts, I can't scroll the list view until I have clicked off the tab that the activity starts on, and then re-select the  tab with the list view inside it.

Note, I can get the list view to focus by calling:
`tabHost.getTabContentView().requestFocus();` but unfortunately, I still can't scroll until I have reselected the tab...

Have any remedies?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide source code of your TabActivity and the layout file with TabHost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - I ditched the tabs in order to simplify the layout.

Comment: This is exact the answer I was expecting! :)